# how to convert value of column defined as character into integer in python

Tags: python, casting

I had a postgresql query where I need to take column defined as character from table and then pass this value to the function where it only accepts integer.So in this case, how can i solve the problem??Can anyone help??

Comment: What do you mean by "defined as character"? Do you mean a digit character? A string of digits? Or an arbitrary character that you want to translate to an integer? Or, hardest of all, an arbitrary string?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Don't forget to use try/except statements in conversion to avoid surprises like this:

```
Python 2.6.6 (r266:84292, Sep 15 2010, 15:52:39) 
[GCC 4.4.5] on linux2
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>> a='a'
>>> int(a)
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
ValueError: invalid literal for int() with base 10: 'a'
```

Solution:

```
try:
    int(myvar)
except ValueError:
    ...Handle the exception...
```

Answer (score 0):

`ord(val)` will give you the integer value of a character. `int(val)` will cast a value into an integer.